# Error al montar volumen lógico sobre directorio +Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Estoy intentado crear una capa de lectura-escritura sobre un directorio NFS, pero al intentar montar el volumen lógico **rwlayer** sobre el directorio /upper con `mount /dev/lubuntu-vg/rwlayer /mnt/upper` me salta el siguiente error:

`Tipo de Sistema de ficheros incorrecto, opción incorrecta, superblo-que incorrecto en overlay, falta la página de códigos o el programa auxiliar, o algún otro error”.`

Estoy trabajando con una máquina cliente(que es donde tengo el problema de montaje) y con una máquina server donde tengo configurado el NFS, el cual he exportado en modo ro a todas las máquinas de la red 192.168.100.4

El directorio nfs exportado en server lo he montado en mi máquina cliente sobre ***/mnt/rmtbin***

**[image: /rmtbin]**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: recuerda darle los permisos a la carpeta `chmod -R 775 /mnt/mrtbin`  en el nfs lo tienes como `ro` en el archivo fstab esto es  solo lecturara debes cambiarlo a rw para que puedas escribir en el reinicio y listo!

Comment: Al final el problema venía de que al volumen rwlayer no le había dado formato .ext4 `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-rwlayer` Muchas gracias de todas formas